# Angular dropdown need to set a default value

Tags: angular, typescript, dropdown

```
 <select [(ngModel)]="detail.State" (ngModelChange) ="onStateChange()" class="form-control">
              <option [ngValue]="null"  disabled selected>Choose State</option>
              <option *ngFor="let option of stateData"  [ngValue]="option.KeywordValueText">{{option.KeywordValueText}}</option>
            </select>  

 <select [(ngModel)]="detail.City" class="form-control">
               <option [ngValue]="null"  disabled selected>Choose City</option>
              <option *ngFor="let option of cityData" [ngValue]="option.KeywordValueText">{{option.KeywordValueText}}</option>
            </select>
```

In my .ts file, I have

```
onStateChange() {
    this.detail.City = 'null';
    let selectedState = this.keywords.State.filter((val: { KeywordValueText: string | undefined; }) => val.KeywordValueText === this.detail.State);
    this.cityData = this.keywords.City.filter((val: { ParentID: any; }) => val.ParentID == selectedState[0].KeywordValueID);
  }
```

I need to have Choose State and Choose City by default. If I change state, I need city as Choose City. Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: you already assigning null to this.detail.city which is good, tell me where you're getting issue now

Comment: Am not sure. But am not getting Choose City while i change State.

Comment: if possible please provide stackblitz example, btw try detectchanges

Comment: this.detail.City = null; should be like this

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the value `null` instead of the string "null" in case someone names a city `"null"`.

Your HTML is already using the value `null` and not the string. So just set the values to `null` during initialization or in `ngOnInit`.

```js
detail = { State: null, City: null };
```

OR

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.detail.State = null;
  this.detail.City = null;
}
```

Do the same in `onStateChange`.

```js
onStateChange() {
  this.detail.City = null;
  ...
}
```

You may have to edit the type of these properties to `string | null`.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-smprf2?file=src/app/app.component.ts

---

If you want to use the string value instead, just remove the square brackets from your HTML, or add single quotes. Square brackets cause the string to be read as JS.

```html
<option ngValue="null" ...>
```

OR

```html
<option [ngValue]="'null'" ...>
```